# Debugging layout xml file - file not loaded into system

Tags: xml, magento

I'm having trouble getting my layout xml file loaded into the system. I need it loaded in adminhtml for a module I'm building, so here's the part of the config that matters:

```
<adminhtml>
<layout>
    <updates>
        <coupsmart_coupon>
            <file>coupsmart_coupon.xml</file>
        </coupsmart_coupon>
    </updates>
</layout>
</adminhtml>
```

Now, the actual layout file, named coupsmart_coupon.xml file, is as follows:

```
<layout>
    <coupsmart_coupon_adminhtml_coup_index>
        <update handle="coupsmart_coupon"/>
        <reference name="content">
            <block type="coupsmart_coupon/adminhtml_forms" name="myform"/>
        </reference>
    </coupsmart_coupon_adminhtml_coup_index>
</layout>
```

Now, to debug this, I put an error in the layout xml file, such as leaving out a closing bracket (>), and I got no exceptions. So I checked the handles using `$this->getLayout()->getUpdate()->getHandles()` in my controller, and I got back `coupsmart_coupon_adminhtml_coup_index` as one of the handles, which is exactly what I named the handle in my layout xml file. Why else would this not be loading?

Note: I have cleared cache and tried again. Still not working. I also do have logs on and exceptions on, so an exception should have shown in my logs. If any other code is needed let me know.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Figured it out, because `adminhtml.xml` doesn't add to the DOM, and the xml file was actually located in `etc/adminhtml.xml` and not `config.xml`. When I moved the layout update to config, it looked as follows:

```
<config>
    <adminhtml>
        <layout>
            <updates>
                <coupsmart_coupon>
                    <file>coupsmart_coupon.xml</file>
                </coupsmart_coupon>
            </updates>
        </layout>
    </adminhtml>
</config>
```

And now it works. Thanks all for helping.

Answer (score 1):

Yout config.xml is:`<config><adminhtml>...</adminhtml></config>` right?

We are talking about Magento 1.7? Did you try to put you layout.xml in

`design/frontend/base/default/layout`?

Are you sure your config.xml is read?

I know, bad question, but: Did you REALLY clear the cache, of the right magento instance? :-)

The config.xml seems correct, so the error is before, I think.

Hope that helps.

Comment: Yes, I wrapped the adminhtml in config (or else none of the module would work). Yes, I put a copy of it in all of the layout files (with no results). Config xml must be read, since I have a menu item in the adminhtml. And the last part: I think I cleared the right cache. I flushed the Magento Cache in System->Cache Management; that would be correct?

Comment: Should be correct, sometimes magento is evil and has problems "clearing" the not used cache, e.g. if you change database tables because Zend_Db caches the tables chemas. Did you have a look into the exception.log in var/log? If the exception is catched, it is written down there and not shown. I often have exception like "unknown block with name ..."

Comment: Grrr, nothing in my exceptions. I've been watching those the whole time. This just confounds me. I recently did change the resource model, but that shouldn't affect it?...

Comment: Ok, last tpp before I go to bed: die() into the block before the class (is the block-file included), then die() into the __construct. And you should think about to install: https://github.com/ikonoshirt/Wee_Developertoolbar it shows you the layout handles which are loaded. If you have an error in the case, this is a problem. And log the blocks and the layout.xml files which are loaded: http://www.fontis.com.au/blog/magento/magento-debugging-loading-blocks-layouts-and-config-files If this doesn't help, I have no idea atm. Good luck!

Comment: Great tool! That's exceedingly helpful. I'm trying to figure out what you mean by die() into the block before the class; I'm pretty sure none of the blocks are even getting loaded because the layout xml isn't loaded. If you're able, could you elaborate? Which block, and which __construct()?

Comment: Your block to verify wether they are NOT loaded. e.g. <?php die('test'); class ...Block { public function __construct() { die('second_test depending on the first die where called');}}

Comment: Nope, no loading of the blocks :/ There must be something basic I'm missing; but shouldn't the template show up in the getFileLayoutUpdatesXml() even if they aren't loaded onto the page? Because I'm not seeing it there at all.

Comment: Alright, I figured it out. Outlined what happened in a comment in the other solution, thanks for your help though! That toolbar will come in handy.

Answer (score 1):

FYI, the file should *probably* be in app/design/default/layout/, please confirm or advise if there is a custom adminhtml design package.

Also, you may need to call Mage::setIsDeveloperMode(true) in index.php, which can be done by adding

```
SetEnv MAGE_IS_DEVELOPER_MODE
```

to your .htaccess file (see index.php for evaluation of this). Break your layout XML, flush the cache backend and you should see an error.

Comment: Maybe I'm using a different version, but I have different folders for frontend and adminhtml; I put the layout xml in all layout folders available, just to make sure it was there (there are 3).

I already have developer mode on. Already flushed the cache with no results.

Comment: Adminhtml layout xml files will be along the path `app/design/adminhtml/PACKAGE/THEME/layout/`. Normally, PACKAGE = "default". You can log/debug the files in `Mage_Core_Model_Layout_Update::getFileLayoutUpdatesXml()` in the [`$updateFiles` `foreach` loop](https://github.com/LokeyCoding/magento-mirror/blob/1.7.0.2/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/Layout/Update.php#L433)

Comment: The problem is not debugging the file; the problem is the layout xml isn't even there. When I call getFileLayoutUpdatesXml(), the blocks that I have in my layout xml are not in there. The file just isn't getting loaded into the system. Do you know what may cause the file to exist but just be ignored? If it is in the layout folder, shouldn't it exist in the layout updates xml even if the handle isn't loaded?

Comment: To be clear, my `getFileLayoutUpdatesXml()` logging suggestion is meant for you to see if your file is in the list. If it isn't in the list of files to be checked with the `is_readable()` call, then there is a configuration issue. If this is the case and if dev mode is truly enabled, breaking your module's `config.xml` should throw a parse error. If not, you have a module declaration file error or a caching problem.

Comment: Got it solved. For some reason, although everything else worked, having my `<layout><update><module><file>` in etc/adminhtml.xml didn't work; when I put it in etc/config.xml, as in <config><adminhtml><layout><update>`, it worked. I have no idea why one worked when the other didn't, considering everything else works in my adminhtml.xml file.

Comment: Well, of couse that would not work, because that file (`adminhtml.xml`) is parsed by the `admin/config` model only for the menu and ACL configuration. Its contents are not merged with the general configuration DOM.